# Place an element in bottom right corner of window (not viewport)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using javacript to place an element in a certain position on the screen (in the bottom right corner). When I resize the page, I want the element to stay in the bottom right corner (outside the viewport). Instead, I'm seeing it move to be in the bottom-right corner of my viewport.

How can I fix this?

I have the following code in my window load function:

```
    $('MyElement').removeClass();
    $('MyElement').css("right", "20px");
    $('MyElement').css("bottom", "55px");
    $('MyElement').css("position", "fixed");
```

It seems I want the opposite of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760998/position-element-at-bottom-right-corner-of-current-window), but using position:fixed did not fix my problem (I'm seeing the same behavior with both fixed and absolute).

Comment: Your jQuery can be dramatically simplified: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/xe392ze2/

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to JS as of last week :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `position: absolute`, but the element should be a direct child of the body tag so that it is positioned absolute relative to the body.  You might need to put `position: relative` on the body tag as well.

```css
.thing {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 55px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

body {
  width: 150vw;
  height: 150vh;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="thing">Hello!</div>
```

```js
$(function(){
  var op=$('.thing').offsetParent();
  var t=op.offset().top;
  var l=op.offset().left;
  var w=op.width();
  var h=op.height();
  var dh=$(document).height();
  var dw=$(document).width();
  var newbottom=t+h-dh+55;
  var newright=l+w-dw+20;
  $('.thing').css('bottom',newbottom+'px').css('right',newright+'px');
  
  });
```

```css
footer {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 background-color:green;
 height: 50px;
  }
.thing {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

body {
  width: 150vw;
  height: 150vh;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer>
<div class="thing">Hello!</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: So if it's presently in a footer element, this will not work?

Comment: Will work if the footer element is the first ancestor that has positioning other than static.

Comment: It will become very tricky if any element that is a parent, grand parent, etc of the element is positioned something other than static.

Comment: I'll see if I can restructure this to be set up in this way and maintain existing functionality. If I can't, is it just a matter of getting creative, or is there a standard way?

Comment: You will need to manually calculate the bottom and right based on the top/left (and width/height) of the element that is the containing element and not positioned static.  You can use `.offsetParent()` to find that element.

Comment: @Cptn_Hammer Updated answer to show how to do it if your element has a parent/container that isn't position static.  Please note that if the offsetParent element changes location (because it's position fixed, or something changes it's top/left), you will need to recalculate yours as well.